# Rename a list of file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I try to rename a list of files in Haskell, and I use following code.

```
let listOfFullPath = ["/home/name/oldFile.txt"]
let outputList = map(\x -> renameFile x  "/home/name/newfile.txt") listOfFullPath
```

When I run the code, I did not see the file is renamed.

Does anyone know why the `renameFile` is not working inside the map()?

I know `renameFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()` and I also try following:

```
let outputList = map(\x -> renameFile x "/home/name/newfile.txt" >> return ()) listOfFullpath
```

Comment: Are you running this in GHCi or is this part of a file you are compiling? In either case, you aren't running an `IO` action. At best, you are defining part of one.

Comment: `let x = print 3` does not print anything: it only defines `x` that, when executed, will print 3. To execute `x` it has to be run inside `main` or some other IO action that is called (not just defined) from `main`. Similarly, `let xs = [print 3, print 4]` does not print anything. In main, if we run `print (length xs)` we get 2 (the length), while the IO actions `print 3, print 4` are still ignored. If we instead use `main = sequence xs` then 3 and 4 are printed. (I'd suggest to review an IO tutorial.)

Comment: I do have main and run it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell is lazily evaluated, so while the type of `outputList` is (probably; I haven't tried) `[IO ()]`, nothing further happens because your code never actually traverses the list.

You'll probably need `mapM_` instead instead of `map`:

```
module Q45965113 where

import System.Directory

go = do
  let listOfFullPath = ["./oldFile.txt"]
  mapM_ (\x -> renameFile x  "./newfile.txt") listOfFullPath
```

You can load this into GHCi and run `go`:

```
Prelude> :load 45965113.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Q45965113        ( 45965113.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Q45965113.
*Q45965113> :! ls *.txt
oldfile.txt
*Q45965113> go
*Q45965113> :! ls *.txt
newfile.txt
```

As you can see, the file has been renamed.

Comment: I can just run  renameFile (oldName newName), and I have no problem to rename a file.